# Ubuntu Mate change icon

Tags: lightdm

With *LightDM GTK + Greeter settings*, I choose the icon type I want to change from the options in *Icons* . But there are no changes in the icons.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.Solution;
* right-click on the desktop and select 'Change Desktop Background'
* there's a tab that says 'themes'. Click on that. Then
* at the bottom of that screen, it should say 'Customise'.
* Click on that. at the top of the window it brings up, a tab should say "Icons'.
that's all.